# $\zeta(n+1) = \frac12 \Bigl(1+\zeta(n)\Bigr)$ for all integers $n\ge 28$

Tags: number-theory, riemann-zeta

It would appear that $$\zeta(n) = \frac12 \Bigl(1+\zeta(n-1)\Bigr)$$ holds true for all integers $n\ge 28$. I first seen this recurrence relation in Abramowitz and Stegun's *Handbook of Mathematical Functions* where there is a table of decimal approximations of $\zeta(n)$ from $1$ to $42$ and after that it says "For $n > 42, \zeta(n+1) = \frac12 \Bigl(1+\zeta(n)\Bigr)$ (page 811). However, after checking numerous other values in Wolfram Alpha, it appears this recurrence holds true as far back as $n=28$

However, searching the internet I cannot find anywhere that validates this statement. I would appreciate any sort of info on where I can learn more about this or if a proof can be produced. I for one do not know too much in depth about $\zeta(z)$ so I do not attempt to try proving on my own, although I would imagine Mathematical Induction is involved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that this is just an approximation to the zeta function using the first two terms in the series 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\zeta(n) \sim 1+ \frac{1}{2^n}+ \cdots.
\end{eqnarray*}
which will give a good approximation because $1/3^n $ and higher terms will be very small for large values of $n$.

Comment: So rather we should have $$\zeta(n) \approx \frac12 \Bigl(1+\zeta(n-1)\Bigr)$$ for large $n$ ? This would make much more sense for it to be included with the approximations page rather than the properties page

Comment: if you sub $\zeta(n-1) \sim 1+ \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$ into that formula it will give $\zeta(n) \sim 1+ \frac{1}{2^n}$.

Answer (score 2):

The formula listed is just an approximation. If it held exactly, we'd have
\begin{align*}
\zeta(2n + 2) = \frac{3}{4} + \frac{1}{4}\zeta(2n)
\end{align*}
for sufficiently large integers $n > 0$, but $\zeta(2m)$ is rational multiple of $\pi^{2m}$ for positive integers $m$, and $\pi$ is transcendental.

Comment: Thus, we would have $\zeta(2n+2)$ would be some rational multiple of $\pi ^{2n}$ rather than $\pi ^ {2n+2}$, a contradiction, correct?

Comment: You'd get $a\pi^{2n+2} =b + c\pi^{2n}$ with $a, b, c\in \mathbb{Q}$ and nonzero, which would contradict the fact that $\pi$ is transcendental. (You can explicitly write down $a$ and $c$ in terms of the Bernoulli numbers, but that's not really relevant.)

Comment: I'd like the more concise notation gotten by reformulation
$$ \begin{array}  {} \zeta(2n+2) &= \frac34 + \frac14 \zeta(2n) \\
 (\zeta(2n+2)-1) +1 &= \frac34 + \frac14 (\zeta(2n)-1) + \frac14 \\
 (\zeta(2n+2)-1) +1 &= 1 + \frac14 (\zeta(2n)-1) \end{array}$$
to $$ (\zeta(2n+2)-1)  = \frac14 (\zeta(2n)-1) $$
because the typical $\zeta(n)-1$ has some nice properties...